# Referencing file to HTML link

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am trying to link a previously saved blog post to my new site and am having no luck getting them to show up. It says file not found. Could someone let me know if I am leaving something out? My prior blog entries are saved in a folder called _posts, which is under a folder for my project, and the project is in another folder called developer.

This is how I have it right now:

```
<p><a href="/_posts/2017-05-26_blog.html></a></p>
</br>

<p><a href="/_posts/2017-06-09_blog.html></a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using absolute paths, those prefixed with `/`, then you'll need to use some kind of server configured to have a proper "web root". If you're looking at these HTML files in your browser directly off of disk these links won't work.

There's a number of web development tools that allow you to quickly and easily spin up a server locally for this purpose.